# How to use Aspera Hot Folder feature to download large files from COS

Tags: ibm-cloud, large-files, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, cloud-object-storage

I have been using Aspera Hot folder Feature to download large files (100GB+) from a vendor server (A). I am trying to do similar downloads from another vendor (B) who has large files on IBM COS. I have HMAC credentials for IBM COS , able to connect using AWS CLI (B) but could not establish same connection using Aspera Desktop application. Any ideas on how to setup a watch folder/hot folder like functionality to download large files from COS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is actually not possible using the aspera provided with COS.

but if you are not afraid of using command line, it is possible with:
https://github.com/IBM/aspera-cli

see:
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/aspera-cli#hot-folder

You will have to use the "cos" plugin (instead of "server" as in doc)

Example:

```
ascli cos node \
--bucket=my_bucket \
--endpoint="https://s3.eu-de.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud" \
--apikey=DsqdsqdSQDSQddqsDQS --crn=crn:v1:bluemix:public:cloud-object-storage:global:a/656435423542ababa5454:ffffffff-5029-abcd-af65-ebc6d2b46b45:: \
upload source_hot \
--to-folder=/Upload/target_hot \
--lock-port=12345 \
--ts=@json:'{"EX_ascp_args":["--remove-after-transfer","--remove-empty-directories","--exclude-newer-than=-8","--src-base","source_hot"]}'
```